# Rails display value from lookup table in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Newbie alert! I hope I can explain my situation accurately and understandably.

I have a model called animals. Another model called statuses. Another called sexes.

From animal.rb model:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :status, :class_name => Status, :foreign_key => :status_id
    belongs_to :sex, :class_name => Sex, :foreign_key => :sex_id
end
```

sex.rb model:

```
class Sex < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :animals
end
```

status.rb model:

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :animals
end
```

In my views/animals/index.html.erb I have this:

```
<% @animals.each do |animal| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= animal.name %></td>
        <td><%= animal.eartag %></td>
        <td><%= animal.sex.sex %></td>
        <td><%= animal.status.status %></td>
...
```

The column in the table displays the sex from the sexes lookup table fine, but the line for status causes the following error:

NoMethodError in Animals#index 
undefined method `status' for nil:NilClass

So I guess Rails is thinking animal.status is nil?? I don't know why it would be when animal.sex is not nil.

Also, I have views/animals/show.html.erb. Part of that is:

```
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:sex_id) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @animal.sex.sex %></dd>
 <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:status_id) %>:</strong></dt>
  <dd><%= @animal.status.status %></dd>
```

And this works fine. I.e. in the columns for Sex and Status, it displays the values from the sex and status columns of the sex and status tables, respectively, as I want the index.html.erb view to do.

I don't know if it makes any difference, but here's animals_controller.rb:

```
class AnimalsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_animal, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /animals
  # GET /animals.json
  def index
    @animals = Animal.all
  end

  # GET /animals/1
  # GET /animals/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /animals/new
  def new
    @animal = Animal.new
  end

  # GET /animals/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /animals
  # POST /animals.json
  def create
    @animal = Animal.new(animal_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @animal.save
        format.html { redirect_to @animal, notice: 'Animal was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @animal }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @animal.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /animals/1
  # PATCH/PUT /animals/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @animal.update(animal_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @animal, notice: 'Animal was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @animal.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /animals/1
  # DELETE /animals/1.json
  def destroy
    @animal.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to animals_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_animal
      @animal = Animal.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def animal_params
      params.require(:animal).permit(:name, :eartag, :reg_num, :sex_id, :date_birth, :date_acquired, :date_removed, :status_id, :num_horns, :sire_id, :dam_id, :source_id, :origin_id, :percent_black, :percent_lilac, :for_sale, :for_sale_status_id, :quality_id, :sale_price, :to_be_culled, :comments, :comments_web, :show_on_website, :core_flock, :birth_id, :rejected_at_birth)
    end
end
```

I hope this makes some kind of sense. Thanks!

Comment: If you're getting `undefined method 'status' for nil:NilClass`, then `animal.status` is indeed `nil`.

Comment: @Santosh, your answer contradicts your comment. You can't have it both ways in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
<%= animal.status.status %>
```

to

```
<%= animal.status.status if animal.status %>
```

This will prevent the error. Will output `animal.status.status` only if `animal.status` is present.

Comment: This is correct, but absolutely contradicts your comment to the question.

Comment: Wow, that did the trick. I had been thinking that because the show.html.erb for an individual animal was working with a similar syntax (and not having any problem with a nil value), that the problem wasn't with an actual nil. But now I realize that way down the list of records there are a couple without any status. And those are causing the whole page to throw an error. Thanks for the help!